# Asynchronous Promise blocking DOM

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, dom, promise

Asynchronous Promises aren't working as I expected in React (specifically React, but I think this will apply to other scenarios). They still seem to be blocking the main thread, essentially freezing my browser.

I've got this method that handles a button click:

```js
onClick() {
  console.time('factorial')
  factorial(8000) // factorial is the culprit!
    .then(n => this.setState({ n }))
  console.endTime('factorial')
}
```

`factorial` returns a promise, and so, as expected, I get `factorial: 2ms` in the console. However, the webpage hangs. This is also evident when taking a look at the performance metrics:

[image: promise callback taking 700+ ms, blocking the DOM]

The Promise takes 700+ ms to evaluate, and for the entire duration, the DOM seems to be blocked. This completely confuses me, since I would expect the DOM to carry on. How can I get my `factorial` function to not block the DOM?

Comment: Can you show us how your `factorial()` function is coded?  If it just runs a big synchronous loop and then resolves the promise that does you absolutely no good at all.  To allow other things to interleave with its operation, it has to actually return control back to the interpreter between cycles of calculation.  It is possible to write a non-blocking, cooperative factorial implementation, but it sounds like your implementation is not that.  Also, you act like the DOM is something that executes.  The DOM is a data structure. So perhaps you are referring to some specific DOM event or activity?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll admit, I lied. The implementation of the code isn't factorial, but a function whose job it is to generate a waveform. Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/zBPMgM2h And, yes, by "block the DOM," I just meant that no DOM Events are being executed. My bad, I should've been a bit more specific.

Comment: Well, by not including the real info here (and frankly misleading us), you didn't get as good an answer as you could have and you basically wasted people's time here.  Please post your REAL code with your REAL objectives.  We are at least 10x more effective when people show us the real code and the real problem.  Theoretical questions often get shrouded in false assumptions by the person writing the question which makes it impossible for us to offer the best help.

Comment: You apparently showed some hypothetical synchronous `factorial()` function that returned a promise and that was indeed based on some faulty assumption.  That would never be done in the real world (no reason for a synchronous function to return a promise), thus rendering this question fairly useless as a reference for anyone else.  Please post real code and real problems.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought that by generalizing my problem, it could more easily be applied for developers in the same boat. I thought it'd be somewhat selfish of me to post my exact code, since that would require everyone to delve into the complexities of the libraries I am using (Bluebird & p5). I apologize if your time has been wasted, and I'll keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: yes that is a popular misconception.  You are not alone, but in any programming problem, we can only make the best recommendation for your situation by seeing your code.  Its not selfish here - its being specific and detailed which helps everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous functions are not threads.

They get paused and put in the background while they are waiting for something outside the JavaScript event loop to happen (like an HTTP response to arrive).

While they are running, they are still running, and tie up the event loop like any other function.

If you want to shunt some processing off to another thread, you'll need to use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). (At least in the context of a web browser; Node has [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)).